Angular Unit Testing Service - Property in service constructor not using value from spyOnProperty
I'm trying to write a negative test for my AuthService that a property in the constructor is set to null if nothing is returned from angularFireAuth. The positive side of this test case is working, and if I modify my mock file directly I can see the outcomes I want. Even with the spyOnProperty mock I have below, when I subscribe to it I can see in console logs that it's returning null.
The problem is that I can't get the actual service constructor to pick up the spyOnProperty returnValue. For a component I would do a fixture.detectChanges but that doesn't work for a service. Is there some way I have to rebuild the service before the constructor picks up the mocked null value?
AuthService Constructor
{
(this.partyCollectionPath);
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: User | null) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = {
          uid: user.uid,
          email: user.email,
          emailVerified: user.emailVerified
        };
        this.liveUid = user.uid
      } else {
        this.userData = null
      }
    });
  }

AngularFireAuthMock
import { User } from '../shared/interface/user';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const authState: User = {
    uid: 'fakeuser',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    emailVerified: true
};
export const AngularFireAuthMock: any = {
    AngularFireAuth: jasmine.createSpyObj('AngularFireAuth', {
//other functions
}),

get authState() {
    return of(authState);
  },

Test Assertion
  it('userData set to null', () => {

    const spy = spyOnProperty(AngularFireAuthMock, 'authState', 'get');
    spy.and.returnValue(of(null))

    AngularFireAuthMock.authState.subscribe((data: any) => {
      
      console.log('subscribe: ', data)
      
    })
    console.log('userData: ', service.userData) 
    // expect(service.userData).toBeNull()

  });

Console Logs

LOG: 'subscribe: ', null


LOG: 'userData: ', Object{uid: 'fakeuser', email: 'test@test.com',
emailVerified: true}


This ended up being my lack of understanding on the fundamental TestBed structure for Angular tests. I finally read the Angular documentation testing services section in full, and realized that the command that essentially builds the service to test is TestBed.inject().
By default in the generated .spec file for a service, that gets added into the beforeEach(). Essentially this meant that the constructor was being built before my spyOnProperty was even being run The solution was to take the TestBed.inject() out of the beforeEach() section, and run it AFTER my spy.
Here is the completed solution:
AuthService
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../interface/user';
//Angularfire Imports
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  userData = {} as User | null
  public partyUserId: string = ''
  public liveUid: string = ''

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,

  ) {
//This is the code I'm trying to test, I subscribe  in the constructor and  assign a property with the user data. If the response is null then I set userData to null.
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: User | null) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = {
          uid: user.uid,
          email: user.email,
          emailVerified: user.emailVerified
        };
        this.liveUid = user.uid
      } else {
        this.userData = null
      }
    });
  }
}

AngularFireAuthMock
import { User } from '../shared/interface/user';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const authState: User = {
    uid: 'fakeuser',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    emailVerified: true
};

export const AngularFireAuthMock: any = {
    AngularFireAuth: jasmine.createSpyObj('AngularFireAuth', {}),

    get authState() {
        return of(authState);
      },

    get user() {
      return this.authState;
    },
  
    set user(value: any) {
      this.authState = value;
    }
}

auth.service.spec.ts
There are two main ways I could have done this, and the actual documentation doesn't imply that one is better than the other. Originally I just took the TestBed.inject() out of the beforeEach() so I could manually place it in each test. I think for a small service that wouldn't be too bad, but I didn't want to have to remember to inject each time so I created two describe blocks with different beforeEach(). I suppose doing it this way, I could just create an entirely different mock file I passed in for the provide useValue instead of using the spyOnProperty. If anyone has a comment on a standard, or better way of doing this let me know!
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreMock } from '../../testing/mock_angularFirestore';
import { AngularFireAuthMock } from '../../testing/mock_angularFireAuth';
import { User } from '../interface/user';
import { of } from 'rxjs';


//This is the first block, where I am just using the AngularFireAuthMock file and the TestBed.inject() is in the beforeEach()
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(
      { providers: [
          { provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: AngularFirestoreMock },
          { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: AngularFireAuthMock }
        ]});

      service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  it('AuthService created Successfully', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('userData populated Successfully', () => {
    const authState: User = {
      uid: 'fakeuser',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      emailVerified: true
    };
    expect(service.userData).toEqual(authState)
    expect(service.liveUid).toEqual(authState.uid)
  });
});

//This is the second describe block where I add in the spyOnProperty right before I do the TestBed.inject(). Now, if I have other tests or assertions to run when authState or userData is null, I can write them here.

describe('AuthService Null checks', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(
      { providers: [
          { provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: AngularFirestoreMock },
          { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: AngularFireAuthMock }
        ]});

    spyOnProperty(AngularFireAuthMock, 'authState', 'get').and.returnValue(of(null))

    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);

  });

  it('userData set to null', () => {

    expect(service.userData).toBeNull()

  });

});


The code inside the subscribe is asynchronous, waits for the API call to complete, but the code below the subscribe is synchronous and does not wait for the asynchronous code above to complete. To force the test to wait for the fake API (asynchronous code) to complete, you need to use fakeAsync and flush.
The console.log ran before the subscribe could complete, which causes this problem!
it('userData set to null', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOnProperty(AngularFireAuthMock, 'authState', 'get');
    spy.and.returnValue(of(null));
    AngularFireAuthMock.authState.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('subscribe: ', data);
    })
    flush();
    console.log('userData: ', service.userData) 
    // expect(service.userData).toBeNull()

}));


Thanks for the response! I tried the fakeAsync & flush() approach, but I got the same console.log results. The subscribe I added to the test was for debugging only, and to see what I get from the authState subscribe to mimic the constructor. Since my goal is to test the logic in the constructor in the end I don't think I would even need the subscribe function in the final test. I feel like there needs to be some way to 'rebuild' the service with the new spyOnProperty mock value so the constructor uses it, since if I change the Mock file directly I get the result.

@RustyShackleford should it be service.afAuth, instead of AngularFireAuthMock same thing we discussed in last answer, in your code you are testing the class and not the instance

I tried setting the spy like this: const spy = spyOnProperty(service.afAuth, 'authState', 'get'); and it worked the same way: the log inside of the subscribe shows null, but looking at the service.userData directly shows the original data from the mock.
I was using this 2017 question to help me originally, what stood out to me was the accepted answer seemed to create a second 'describe' block inside of the first, and created a second beforeEach. That didn't work either, though.

For the record, this is what I just tried, and the constructor subscribe is still going after the original Mock data, and not the spyOnProperty:
`describe('null', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
const spy = spyOnProperty(AngularFireAuthMock, 'authState', 'get');
spy.and.returnValue(of(null))
});
it('inside IT - userData set to null', (() => {

  console.log('userData: ', service.userData)

}));

})`
This was inside of the original describe, and the console.log still shows the object from the original mock file.

@RustyShackleford Could you replicate the issue here stackblitz so that I can validate it, the code provided is not complete

I tried to get a fork of your jasmine project working, but ran into some weird dependency issues. I imported all of the necessary files in full, so you can see what's going on. I tried to copy my auth.service.spec.ts into the app.component.spec.ts but that's where I ran into issues. Stackblitz Fork. I added comments to shared/services/auth.service.ts and auth.service.spec.ts, as well as the testing/mock_angularFireAuth.ts.

Ok, I figured it out! I needed to use service = TestBed.inject(AuthService); AFTER I had set the spy inside my test. For now, that means I had to actually pull it out of the  beforeEach() and I'm adding it to each test individually. I'm going to test a couple of other ways I can do this cleaner, and then I'll write up a full answer with the complete files.

Done, I absolutely appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Sometimes just bouncing ideas off of someone gets you to the solution! In fact, without your help from the last question, I would never have been able to replicate the spyOnProperty null mock in the first place.
